# Shapley values for glmnet using R's iml package

Tags: r, glmnet, iml, shapley

I'm unable to use the `iml` package in R to find shapley values for `glmnet` models.

It seems like the problem might be related to the fact that `glmnet()` and `predict.glmnet()` expect matrices, while the `x.interest` argument in `iml::Shapley$new()` expects a data frame, and so something is being incorrectly converted, but I'm not sure.

The most reasonable thing I've tried is below. Because of the following note in the `iml::Predictor()` documentation, I make sure my prediction function returns estimated probabilities for both classes: "Note: In case of classification, the model should return one column per class with the class probability."

```
library(dplyr)
library(iml)
library(glmnet)
df <- filter(iris, Species != 'setosa')
X <- as.matrix(select(train, -Species))
y <- droplevels(df$Species)
fit <- glmnet(X, y, family = 'binomial', lambda = 0.03)

predfun <- function(model, newdata) {
  preds <- predict(model, as.matrix(newdata), type = 'response') # probabilities
  return(cbind(1 - preds, preds)) # for both classes 
}

# Pass data frames, as requested
mod <- Predictor$new(fit, as.data.frame(X), predict.function = predfun) 
shapley <- Shapley$new(mod, x.interest = as.data.frame(X[1, ]))
```

This gives me the following: `Error in predict.glmnet(model, as.matrix(newdata), type = "response"): The number of variables in newx must be 4`

I'm not really sure what is being passed to `predict.glmnet()` that doesn't have four variables (it doesn't seem to have to do with an intercept from things I've tried). I've looked at the source code for `Shapley$new()` and also stepped for quite a while through a call via `browser()` but wasn't able to come up with anything useful.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure how to solve this API nightmare...

You can try exact KernelSHAP:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)

df <- filter(iris, Species != 'setosa')
X <- as.matrix(select(df, -Species))
y <- droplevels(df$Species)
fit <- glmnet(X, y, family = 'binomial', lambda = 0.03)

library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

s <- shapviz(kernelshap(fit, X, bg_X = X))
sv_importance(s, kind = "bee", show_numbers = TRUE)
sv_dependence(s, colnames(X), color_var = NULL) &
  ylim(-4, 4)
sv_waterfall(s, row_id = 1)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]